# Components needed for a VPN

Tags: vpn, mac-osx-server, adsl, osx-snow-leopard

first of all, I asked this question on SuperUser.com, but no one there could help me.

Well, we eventually got our Mac Mini Server. We now want to set up a small Remote Access VPN using this Mac Mini Server.

Firstly we are not sure of the components needed additionally to the server to setup this VPN. We currently have the following:

- 1 Mac Mini Server
- 1 Firewall Router (Billion 802.11g ADSL2+ router with VPN capabilities [it says so on the box]), we currently use this as our internet connection and resides X.X.0.1 on our network.
- 4Mbps ADSL connection (Should this line have VPN capability enabled by the service provider?)

We are not sure what else needs to be included to enable our small VPN. Any advice would be really helpful?

Comment: OpenVPN is incredibly easy to setup. If you're a Mac shop, I would highly suggest OpenVPN Server + Viscosity client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our problem was solved by just getting a DynDNS url and then forwarding the port on our router to the Mac mini server. We just forwarded some of the hidden ports that are not forwarded by default and voila. Everything worked.

Thanks for all the advice. It was after all not as cumbersome as I anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this web [site](http://www.billion.com/product/adsl.html) from the specs and given what I see I do not believe your router will actually initiate or terminal a VPN.  They only mention that they will probably allow a VPN through through the firewall.  I could be looking at the wrong page page though.

I have a really strong preference for OpenVPN so I would suggest the that what you need, is to install [tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/) on your server and client machines.  You would need to forward traffic your firewall into your server for the OpenVPN port (default: udp/1194).  After that you need a strong understanding of routing to get it all configured.  The OpenVPN and Tunnelblick docs should help you with this.